# read more link in post is not working wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How to bring the read more link at the end of the post in the home page of my blog?

Basically in  my home page, it display all the content of the post, i would like to limit the characters to display

thanks

Comment: the_content('read more...');  this code is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have used the `<!-- More -->` functionality in your post, the content will be cut off on the home page where you put the tag.

```
  <?php the_content("Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
```

See the beginning of this [article.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "MORE" tag. Place it where you want the break to occur. It will add your "Read More" link.